# Call injected java script's function from GWT

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, gwt, javascript-injection

I have GWT application, html file and javascript file. In GWT application, I am loading html files in GWT HTML Panel and then injecting javasript on that. I have defined couple of functionality like "submit", "cancel" etc.. in javasript file. I have corresponding button in GWT client page too. Now, when i click on submit button on gwt client page, it should invoke "submit" function of javascript file.

code from javascript file:

```
$('#submitButton').click( function () {
      alert('submit clicked');
      dosomething();
    }
  });
```

I have tried using JSNI as below from GWT client page.

```
public native JavaScriptObject submitForm()/*-{
        return $doc.submitButton(); // tried with $wnd.submitButton() as well.
    }-*/;
```

but it does not work and throws following error

```
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: (TypeError)  $doc.submitButton is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems pretty clear - you are invoking `submitButton` which is not a function (it's probably `undefined`, unless you did something else besides the code shown). You should probably do something like: `$wnd.jQuery('#submitButton').click()`.

Comment: Thanks Igor. With your suggestion, now I am not getting error, but it is also not hitting javascript function. I tried by giving random name like $wnd.jQuery('#submitButtonDoesNotExist').click(), i was expecting some error, but no error and nothing happens.

Comment: Can you trigger the click from the Javascript console (the one in Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, etc.)? Just put there `jQuery('#submitButton').click()` (no need for the `$wnd` part here). Have you checked you really have an element with id `submitButton` in the DOM when you try to trigger the call from GWT?

Comment: Thanks Igor. Added an element with id submitButton in html file as well and it worked.